# How to handle inline <b> when using jade as a multi language template engine

Tags: pug

I am working on a website that requires more than 6 languages.

That is a lot so I decide to develop a simple language engine so that the translators will not need to play with the raw HTML, which is quite possible to lead to a mess-up.

I found that I can inject content from a JSON to jade and render them into HTML, which is quite useful.

but later I realized that there is a problem for many cases when you have some very simple words that are having some inline tags, like `<b></b>` or `<u></u>`, for example:

```
<p>This is a sentence needed to be <b>immediately</b> translated into Chinese</p>
```

this would be like this in Jade:

```
p
  | This is a sentence needed to be
  b immediately
  | translated into Chinese
```

So the template would be something like:

```
p
  | #{sentence1}
  b #{emphasis-word}
  | #{sentence2}
```

and the JSON would be like:

```
{
  "sentence1":"This is a sentence needed to be",
  "emphasis-word":"immediately",
  "sentence2":"translated into Chinese"
}
```

When the Chinese translator sees this JSON file he'd be very confused.

I hope I can directly put simple HTML tags in the content, like:

The template:

```
p #{sentence}
```

The JSON

```
"sentence":"This is a sentence needed to be <b>immediately</b> translated into Chinese"
```

So the Chinese translator and all other translators will only need to know a little about `<b>` and `</b>`, which is quite easier.

Is there anyway I can achieve that?

I searched for a while but did not find something simple.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try unescaped buffered code syntax ?

http://jade-lang.com/reference/#unescapedbufferedcode

You just have to switch from

```
p #{sentence}
```

to

```
p !{sentence}
```